# How to take all rows from a table who stacks between two dates?

Tags: php, mysql, database

My question is how i can take all rows from a table who stack between two dates.

Here is my query:

```
   $sql = "SELECT cars.brand,cars.model,cars.reg_num,cars.horse_powers,cars.color FROM cars INNER JOIN clients_cars ON cars.id=clients_cars.cars_id WHERE cars.id IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT clients_cars.cars_id FROM clients_cars WHERE (rent_date between '$d1' AND '$d2') AND (return_date between '$d1' AND '$d2') AND ((return_date > '$d1') OR (rent_date < '$d2')))";
```

It's works but it does only half of my wish.

Here is my table :

[image]

I want to take to show all cars who is rented between two dates even if one of the dates is stacked with other and the other is not.

For example i add 2014-12-04 and 2014-12-13 and it shows me only the car with id=5. It should show me car with id=8 because its already rented at 2014-12-02 and will be return at 2014-12-06 and should show me the car with id=2 because the car will be rented from 2014-12-10 and he is looking for car till 2014-12-13...

I hope you understood me. I will need some help pls :)

Comment: `WHERE (rent_date between '$d1' AND '$d2') OR (return_date between '$d1' AND '$d2')`

Comment: what do you need to receive for given d1 and d2? available or unavailabe cars? your query gives you neither.

Comment: mm nope... it doesn't work. Its still cant find all dates who stack. I add December 3rd till December 5th and its show me only car with id=5 but doesn't show me the car with id=8 wich is rented in this period.

Comment: d1 and d2 are period variables. $d1=start period  $d2=end period. When a user add a period through the variables i want to show him all the cars who are unavailable for this period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this sql:

```
      $sql = "SELECT cars.brand,cars.model,cars.reg_num,cars.horse_powers,cars.color FROM cars LEFT JOIN clients_cars ON cars.id=clients_cars.cars_id  
WHERE (rent_date between '$d1' AND '$d2') OR (return_date between '$d1' AND '$d2')";
```

Comment: This way it gives me back all the rows in the table no matter of the parameters i add

Comment: Yes it worked but not perfect but i found the perfect way. 

 $sql = "SELECT cars.brand,cars.model,cars.reg_num,cars.horse_powers,cars.color FROM cars INNER JOIN clients_cars ON cars.id=clients_cars.cars_id WHERE cars.id IN 
        (SELECT DISTINCT clients_cars.cars_id FROM clients_cars WHERE (rent_date between '$d1' AND '$d2') OR (return_date between '$d1' AND '$d2') OR ((return_date>'$d2')AND(rent_date<'$d1')))";

Comment: This is the exactly query which i needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query

```
"SELECT DISTINCT cars.id,cars.* FROM cars INNER JOIN clients_cars ON cars.id=clients_cars.cars_id WHERE 
    (clients_cars.rent_date between '$d1' AND '$d2') OR (clients_cars.return_date between '$d1' AND '$d2')";
```